# robocopy - when does it delete files from destination?

Tags: windows, robocopy

I want to overwrite older files in the destination but *not* delete files which are only present in the destination.

From https://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html I understood that `/XO` might do exactly that but I also understood that it is possible to delete files from the destination (if they have no counterpart in the source). When exactly does this second behaviour (which I want to avoid) occur?

Comment: no answer to the question, but why don't you just use `xcopy` or `copy-item`? it would overwrite all old files in the destination, but not delete files which are only present in the destination. like `copy-item c:\source\* c:\destination -force`

Answer (score 10):

When you use either one of two options:

- **/PURGE** : Delete dest files/folders that no longer exist in source.
- **/MIR** : MIRror a directory tree - equivalent to /PURGE plus all subfolders (/E)

example:

- robocopy **/PURGE** c:\source d:\destination
- robocopy **/MIR** c:\source d:\destination

Then you will delete files in the destination if they do not exist in the source.

Robocopy will also default to *"By default Robocopy will only copy a file if the source and destination have different time stamps or different file sizes."*

I would also suggest that you look into:

- **/COPY**:copyflag[s] : What to COPY (default is /COPY:DAT)
                    (copyflags : D=Data, A=Attributes, T=Timestamps
                     S=Security=NTFS ACLs, O=Owner info, U=aUditing info).

example:

- robocopy **/COPY:DAT** c:\source d:\destination

That will make sure you get the same timestamps for the files that will be copied.

Answer (score 1):

If you use /PURGE  and also have /XX in your options then PURGE will not delete files or folders because /XX makes Robocopy ignore them.   Remove  /XX from your options and Purge will work and each deleted file will be shown in the log as an *EXTRA File.  Directories will be shown as *EXTRA Dir.    The Extras will be deleted from the destination address